# Exact Match of Word using grep

Tags: linux

I have data in file.txt as follows

```
BRAD CHICAGO|NORTH SAMSONCHESTER|
CORA|NEW ERICA|
CAMP LOGAN|KINGBERG|
NCHICAGOS|ESTING|
CHICAGO|MANKING|
OCREAN|CHICAGO|
CHICAGO PIT|BULL|
CHICAGO |NEWYORK|
```

Question 1: 
I want to search for the exact match for word "CHICAGO" in first column and print second column. 
Output should look like:

```
MANKING
NEWYORK
```

Question 2: 
If multiple matches found then can we limit the out to only one ? so that the output will be only MANKING or NEWYORK

I tried below

```
grep -E -i "^CHICAGO" file.txt | awk -F '|' '{print $2}'
```

but i am getting below output

```
MANKING
BULL
NEWYORK
```

Expected output for Question 1:

```
MANKING
NEWYORK
```

Expected output for Question 2:

```
MANKING
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about an `awk` solution?

```
awk -F'|' '$1 == "CHICAGO"{print $2}' file
```

to only print one output, exit once you have a match, i.e.

```
awk -F'|' '$1 == "CHICAGO"{print $2; exit}' file
```

Making that more generic, you can pass in a variable, i.e.

```
awk -v trgt="CHICAGO" -F'|' '{targ="^" trgt " *$"; if ( $1 ~ targ ) {print $2}}' file
```

The " *$" regex limits the match to zero or more trailing spaces without any extra chars at the end of the target string. So this will meet your criteria to match skip matching `CHICAGO PIT|BULL`.

AND this can be further reduced to

```
awk -v trgt="CHICAGO" -F'|' '{ if ( $1 ~ "^" trgt " *$" ) {print $2}}' file
```

constructing the regex "in-place" in with the comparison.

So you could use more verbose variable names to "describe" how the regex is being constructed from the input and the regex "wrappers" (as in the 3rd example) OR, you can just combine the input variable with the regex syntax in place. That is just a matter of taste or documentation conventions.

You might want to include a comment to explain you are constructing a regex test that would look like the `$1 ~ /^CHICAGO *$/`.

IHTH

Comment: awk is also ok. But when i run given awk command, it is displaying all the records if it matches CHICAGO in first column. I want exact match from first column, so the data like NCHICAGOS shouldn't be matched with CHICAGO.

Comment: Yes, I've fixed that now. See my edits. Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: great!!. it is working. Do you know how to avoid spaces ?  example if i have data as CHICAGO |NEWYORK, i have space after CHICAGO but i still want to display NEWYORK

Comment: `awk -F'|' '{if ($1 ~ /^CHICAGO */) {print $2}}' file` meets your immediate need, but converting string input into a reg-ex is one of my `awk` blind spots. I would have expected `awk -v trgt="CHICAGO" -F'|' '{targ="/^" trgt "[ ]*/"; if ($1 ~ targ) {print $2}' file` to work, but it didn't (get regex syntax error). Maybe someone can help out here? Thanks and good luck.

Comment: Well, it is not working if i have data as given in original post  CHICAGO PIT|BULL|  .  I want exact match for CHICAGO in first column ignoring space. Can we do trim of spaces for first column before eve matching with CHICAGO ? this will solve the problem i guess. Like TRIM ($1) = "CHICAGO"

Comment: @skv , why not try doing it yourself? Surely you can try to build on top of shellter 's answer. Also, if you find this answer to be helpful, at least pay your respect by upvoting it. Second, your question says exact match, trimming white space and the like no longer complies with this requirement.

Comment: Did you try my code? When I run it, I get the same output as you specified. Let me know.

Comment: @Perplexabot: with all respect, i am trying at my side also on how to remove spaces at variable side using ${variable} .  Also at the end i will definitely up vote all the answers given in this post as always i did in my other posts too. It is just 5 minutes gentleman shellter given some answers. Please give us sometime so that I will try from my end and post answers if i found any.

Comment: @shellter: Yes I tried your code, but I think it is even considering data after space. you mentioned trgt " *"  somehow it is considering CHICAGO PIT and i am getting BULL also in output.  sorry i know linux but not all these variables we can give inside some functions.

Comment: @Perplexabot : I understand your frustration and have experienced it many times, but at skv has written a good beginner's question and I'm happy to help. This is why I close all my comments to multiple readers with "Good luck to all"!

Comment: AH, I read the 3 line output as your required output, now I see it was you BAD output. I can fix it. back in a few secs.

Comment: OK, check out revised solution at end. Add an `;exit` after the `print $2` if you want only one output (it will be the first match). Good luck to all.

Comment: @shellter: working perfect. If you don't mind, can you please explain   targ="^" trgt " *$";.     so you have defined two targ varible as above.  when i changed the sequence as trgt " *$" targ="^" then it is throwing an error. how exactly awk know to consider CHICAGO to start from beginning of line and end followed by spaces ?

Comment: @skv : Note that `targ` is one variable and `trgt` is a different variable. The input from the cmd line via `-v targ="CHICAGO"` is one value. By "gluing together" the reg-ex syntax with the `targ` variable, I created a new variable that will do the actual matching via the `$1 ~ trgt` test.

Comment: The `"^" (as in the `grep` solution now missing, anchors the search to the front of the string. The `" *$"` is more reg-ex speak. It means match zero or more spaces at the end of the string. the `zero or more` is the critical bit. No space char, or 1-n spaces are all allowed. But space chars are the only extra chars allowed at the end of the matched string.

Comment: It's all al lot to take in the first time you deal with this, dbl-variables, regex rules, etc. Let it sink in a day. And  work thru the [Awk Tutorial](http://grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html) to get power user status in `awk`. Also good [Sed Tutorial](http://grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html) will show you a lot about regex matching in a *nix context. No need to get into the advanced commands of `sed` though as you should do any logic processing with `awk`. Good luck to all!

Answer (score 3):

Here are some more ways:

## Using `grep` and `cut`:

```
grep "^CHICAGO|" file.txt | cut -d'|' -f2
```

## Using `awk`

```
awk -F"|" '/^CHICAGO\|/{print $2}' file.txt
```

---

For question 2 simply pipe it to head, i.e:

```
grep "^CHICAGO|" file.txt | cut -d'|' -f2 | head -n1
```

Similarly for the `awk` command.